# How to customize angular based kendo notification element with close button and some time to autohide

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I want to customize angular based kendo notification element with both autohiding time and close button.
here have look around what i have tried till now:->

app-custom-toast.ts:-> it's a common toast component.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { someservice } from './someservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-toast',
  templateUrl: './custom-toast.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-toast.component.css']
})
export class CustomToastComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() public ignore: EventEmitter<undefined> = new EventEmitter();
  toastMessage : string;
  constructor(private cdr : ChangeDetectorRef,private gls : someservice) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gls.toastMsgValue.subscribe((data : string)=>{
      this.toastMessage = data;
    })
  }

  public ignoreNotification(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.ignore.emit();
}

}
```

custom-toast.component.html:->

```
<div style="width: 100% !important;">
      <span class="message">{{ toastMessage }}</span>
      <span class="k-icon my-custom-icon-class" (click)="ignoreNotification($event)"></span>
    </div>
```

now i am trying to display toast message by accessing toastcomponent from different component like below:->

```
import { someservice } from './someservice.service';
import { CustomToastComponent } from './CustomToastComponent';
@Component({
  selector: 'diff',
  templateUrl: './diff.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diff.component.css']
})
export class DiffComponent implements OnInit {

showtoast() {
  this.toast("msg1", 5000, 'success');
}
   

 toast(toastMsg: string, toastTiming: number, toastType: "none" | "success" | "warning" | "error" | "info") {

    this.someservice.toastMsg.next(toastMsg);
    const notificationRef: NotificationRef = this.notificationService.show({
      content: CustomToastComponent,
      hideAfter: toastTiming,
      position: { horizontal: 'center', vertical: 'top' },
      animation: { type: 'fade', duration: 400 },
      type: { style: toastType, icon: true },
      height: 50
    });
    if (notificationRef) {
      notificationRef && notificationRef.content && notificationRef.content.instance.ignore.subscribe(() => notificationRef.hide());
    }
  }
```

diff.component.html:->

```
<button type="button" (click)="showtoast()">show toast</button>
```

this working perfectly fine but when we try to show toast 2 times with 2 different messages, both toasts having the same messages i know this is because of behavior subject which i am using, I am not able to update messages properly for each toast, any help would be appreciated.

because of behavior subject both error and success type are having same message refer below image[image]

Comment: were u able to figure out this? I'm looking for a workaround solution, I think Kendo don't support dynamic time value, so the notification will only get hidden after the time specified is finished..

Answer (score -1):

i have some doubts what does `this.notificationService.show()` function does , if possible share the function definition,

Comment: can you see above code properly, everything is there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).